# What's the idea behind a network address?

Tags: networking, ip-address, lighttpd

I want to block an entire ip range from my webserver but I'm not sure if it's possible with lighttpd. What exactly is the idea behind a network address for example 10.0.0.0/8 or 176.4.8.0/24? Especially the backslash and the number confuse me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the netmask. (A binary mask that tells the router which part of the IP to use)

/24 stands from 24 ones so 174.4.8.0/24

10110000.00000010.00000100.00000000 Address
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 Netmask

This is kind of a pain to get right but its not hard
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork